# Why “get” method is not there for a ES6 “Set”?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ecmascript-6, set

I am talking about ES6's `Set` function.

```
let set = new Set();
set.add("1", { Name: "myName", Age: 13 })
set.add("2", { Name: "yourName", Age: 14 })
console.log(set);
```

To get some value you have to loop through the set and get the value. Ofcouse we can use `has` method to verify before looping.

But what may be the reason to avoid a `get` method where we can pass a key to get access to the Values of that?

Comment: What would be the purpose of getting a known element of a set?

Comment: I have changed the example in question. Can't we use set as a dictionary ? if yes, I meant that `set.get("2")` gives result as  `{ Name: "yourName", Age: 14 }`

Comment: Are you thinking of a `Map` maybe?

Comment: `Map` we can use.... but not the unique keys...right ?.. I can go with map... I was just thinking that `Set` might have better performance in retrieving data since the keys can be made unique.

Comment: A `Set` is not equivalent to a dictionary, it's just a set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mistaking [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). `Set` is for a set of unique values, not key/value mappings. Hence there's no "get" because there's nothing to get; if you have a value that's in the set, you already have it. `Map` is for key/value mappings.

Your example code is only adding `"1"` and `"2"` to the set, not the objects you're passing as the second argument (that second argument is completely ignored by [`Set.prototype.add`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/add)).

`Map`, of course, *does* have `get`:

```js
let map = new Map();
map.set("1", { Name: "myName", Age: 13 })
map.set("2", { Name: "yourName", Age: 14 })
console.log(map.get("1"));
```

Comment: I came to know about map, but just thought of `Set` might have better performance in retrieving data since the keys can be made unique. So if `Set` cannot store like a dictionary as we do with `Map`, then I have to use `Map` only